# How do I dynamically echo the total sum of column data from a date range search result with php?

Tags: php

I have a search feature that displays records from a database based on date range search. What I want to do is echo the total sum of the "refund_amount" column that is displayed after the date range search. I know how to get the total sum from all the records from the database. I need to echo only the sum of the "refund_amount" column that is being displayed after the date range search. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  include('includes/connect.php');
  if (isset($_GET["status"])) { $status  = $_GET["status"]; } else { $status=0; };
  if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=0; };
  if (isset($_GET["d2"])) { $d2  = $_GET["d2"]; } else { $d2=0; };
  $result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM rma_list WHERE refund_date BETWEEN :a AND :b");
  $result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
  $result->bindParam(':b', $d2);
  $result->execute();
  for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
  ?>

  <tr class="record">
  <td><?php echo $row['rma_id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['order_date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['rma_request_date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['rma_number']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['order_number']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['so_number']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['vendor_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['vendor_ra']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['customer_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['credit_memo_number']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['refund_amount']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['refund_date']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
  </tr>



  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Well add that col up as you go round the loop and then print it after the loop has finished

Comment: Does that code actually produce any output?

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, 

Thanks for the quick reply. Would you mind showing me an example on how to add the column, please. I am still learning php, so I am not sure as to how to go about doing it. Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(refund_amount) AS total FROM rma_list WHERE refund_date BETWEEN :a AND :b` or in loop `$total += $row['refund_amount'];`

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, Yes, the code does produces the output perfectly, based on the by date range search.

Comment: AbraCadaver, if I use your code example and run it, all the fields return an "undefined index", I believe it is because of eliminating the SELECT *. Also, using the loop $total += $row['refund_amount']; will sum all the "refund_amount" data from the database. I need to only display the sum total of what is being displayed dynamically by the date range search.

Comment: the issue right now is that you're outputting the data as you retrieve each row, and at that point you don't have all the data to know the sum yet. So you have a few options. 1. You could change your SQL to `SELECT *, SUM(refund_amount) as sum_total FROM `... so the `refund_amount` is known at this point. But now you're returning duplicate data for each row (this may be a small enough issue that it'd work fine). 2. You could loop through all of your data once and store it in a PHP array and then output that array in a second array. 3. as @AbraCadaver mentioned you could just do a 2nd query.

Comment: Your query only returned rows in that date range so `$total += $row['refund_amount'];` will only only be a total of those in that date range.

Comment: WOUNDEDStevenJones, Seems like using SELECT *, SUM(refund_amount) as sum_total FROM rma_list WHERE refund_date BETWEEN :a AND :b, only returns 1 set of data within the date range selected. For example, if I select date range 08/01/2018 to 08/14/2018 the result should display 3 rows of data, but using the code you suggested only returns 1 row of data out of the 3 total rows that are within the date range selected.

Comment: I also tried to use the $total += $row['refund_amount']; loop, but it displays the total sum of ALL the data in the "refund_amount" column from the database. The idea is ONLY display the total sum of the "refund_amount" data displayed from the date range search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in PHP code

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');
if (isset($_GET["status"])) { $status  = $_GET["status"]; } else { $status=0; };
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=0; };
if (isset($_GET["d2"])) { $d2  = $_GET["d2"]; } else { $d2=0; };
$result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM rma_list WHERE refund_date BETWEEN :a AND :b");
$result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
$result->bindParam(':b', $d2);
$result->execute();

// initialise a variable for the counter
$tot = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
      <tr class="record">
          <td><?php echo $row['rma_id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['order_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['rma_request_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['rma_number']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['order_number']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['so_number']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['vendor_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['vendor_ra']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['customer_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['credit_memo_number']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['refund_amount']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['refund_date']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php

    // accumulate the amount in the new var
    $tot += $row['refund_amount'];
}
?>
    <tr class="totals">
        <td colspan="10"> TOTAL Refund</td>
        <td><?php echo $tot; ?></td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

The table layout may need a little work, but I hope you get the idea from this code

Comment: Hey RiggsFolly, Thanks so much for your help with the code. It worked perfectly!!!